# Dilemma of "forbade me to use" and "forbade me using"

Tags: negation, infinitive-vs-gerund, infinitive-phrases

Consider the sentence:

> "My teacher forbade me to use mobile phone in the class."

Is it right to rewrite the sentence as:

> "My teacher forbade me using mobile phone in the class." ?

Please highlight the differences of the usages of "forbade me to use"  and "forbade me  using" with some examples.

Comment: Amit, please disregard the minuses: Here is a list of verbs like forbid that all function the same way: TO-infinitive or gerund: ADVISE, RECOMMEND, ALLOW, PERMIT, FORBID, REQUIRE and here is the link: http://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-advise-recommend-allow-permit-forbid-require

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence shows correct use of the "forbid to" construction, although it was missing a word before "mobile phone". Also, we usually say "in class" rather than "in the class". Maybe it should be something like this:

> "My teacher forbade me to use my mobile phone in class."

However, your second sentence is incorrect English. If you are going to use the gerund of the verb (e.g. "using") then you need to use the construction "forbid **from**":

> My teacher forbade me from using my mobile phone in class.

There's no difference in meaning between those two sentences. More examples of using "forbid" can be found [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forbid).

Comment: No, the second sentence is not wrong. Forbid and prohibit can be followed by ING. My parents forbid me staying out late/my staying out late.

Comment: here are the RULES for this group of verbs: http://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-advise-recommend-allow-permit-forbid-require The authorities forbade entering the park because of a bush fire.

Answer (score -2):

Both sentences are right.

The slight difference in meaning is this:
/She forbade me/ ||to|| use = you may not have used it already. This is the notion.

VERSUS
/She forbade me/ /using/ = you have used it before. The idea of using precedes  in meaning the idea of forbidding.

The French linguist Adamczewski provides the best explanation of this in French about English. Unfortunately, it has not been translated into English.

**Grammaire linguistique de l'anglais** Henri Adamczewski, Claude Delmas You can find it and download from the Internet and read it if you read French.

I like to play tennis = I like ||to|| play tennis. The **TO** is an operator and it sets up a relationship between I like and play tennis.
It creates a relationship between the SUBJECT and the PREDICATE. "By becoming a predicate, the verbal  notion, which at the outset [plain form] refers to a concept (the idea of playing tennis) sees its range of application limited to the subject with which it has entered into a relationship through the relater TO."

I like playing tennis, on the other hand, is: I like||playing tennis. The lack of an operator (TO) is expressed as:  Ø.  I like Ø playing tennis.  So, we have V1  Ø V2, which means Verb 1 NO OPERATOR Verb 2. (the 1 and 2 should be subscripts but that does not work here). Playing tennis is the notion and it is also the direct object of I like. The verb **like** is a "presupposing" verb; if you like something, some thing precedes your liking.

Forbid [pronoun or noun]  works the same way. The difference in meaning is slight but there.

1) She forbade me ||to|| use . The relationship is between her forbidding me and use.

2) She forbade me //using. The relationship is between using something which precedes notionally the forbidding.

You may not agree with this, but there is definitely a difference between the two.

Comment: Neither construction informs us whether there has been previous use. *Forbade me to use* is much easier on my ear than *forbade me using"

Comment: There is a basic difference in English between to-verb and ing: I like to play tennis sets up a relationship between /I  like/ TO and /play tennis/ versus /I like playing/ /tennis/. The same thing is operant in forbade me using and forbade me to use.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being easy on the ear. The structure verb TO verb versus verb followed by ING is a major structure in English. Other verbs follow the same pattern.

Comment: I think what folks are stuck on is the "me". *My teacher forbade me using a mobile phone in class.* seems like it should be *My teacher forbade using mobile phones in class.* It's not typical for folks to say things like "My job requires me working late." instead of "My job requires working late." or "My job requires me to work late."

Comment: forbid + indirect object + gerund is fine. Here's a modern example: 2-No sailing on tourist boats. There is not an actual law that ***forbids Cubans getting on boats and ships*** http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/05/15/cuba-s-12-most-absurd-prohibitions-that-tourists-may-never-notice.html,

Comment: So, forbids my verb+ ing// rather than me is the 100% correct way to say it. That said, one does get: forbid me + verb + ING rather than forbid my + verb+ing. The indirect object is the formal way to say it (my) but one does get a lot of me, too.

Comment: People who don't understand this explanation are bound to downvote it. This morning (EST) I'm finding someone is going through my answers and doing that.

Comment: Use of a [possessive pronoun before the gerund](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/gerunds-pronouns/) might improve the clarity of this answer to some readers. If I understand correctly, in the second construct, you are treating "using" as a noun. "My teacher forbade my using mobile phones," does sound like a standard construct to me.

Comment: Long live the clueless.